# Recursive Method with Multiple Arguments

Tags: recursion, parameters, racket

I'm new to Racket programming and I wanted to know how to define a method that will be able to be called recursively and has three parameters (three numbers).
I know how to define functions and variables but I'm puzzled here mostly on the multiple parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All Racket(scheme) functions can be called recursively, but to work they must be designed appropriately. This invariably depends on what you are trying to do, which you have failed to mention. As it is, there's little need for recursion on three numbers. Recursion is most often used to iterate over data structures composed of lists. So a more likely scenario would be a function that takes a list of three numbers (or any amount):

```
(define (sum lst)
  (if (null? lst) 0
    (+ (car lst) (sum (cdr lst)))))

(sum '(1 2 3))       => 6
(sum '())            => 0
(sum '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) => 21
```

A more efficient implementation uses a helper function that passes the running sum to the recursive call, allowing for a tail call - which doesn't grow the stack.

```
(define (sum lst)
  (define (sum-helper lst sum)
    (if (null? lst) sum
      (sum-helper (cdr lst) (+ (car lst) sum))))
  (sum-helper lst 0))
```

You will notice that sum-helper has an additional parameter, which you had asked about. As you can see, a function call is just a list - as long as you want (within reason). The first symbol is the function and the rest are parameters.

Please provide more details should this not suffice.

Comment: Invoking the X-Y problem for "how do you define and call a function?" Seriously?

Comment: My first answer on stackoverflow and I get this?! 

I'm not familiar with your "X-Y" problem, sorry. If I catch your drift, you think he's asking how to define and call a function, which I was unable to answer. But, if you'll read the question again, you will see that OP knows how to define functions. I read this as a request for help on recursive functions/calls in particular. No matter the case, you must admit the OP's question is rather nebulous. I couldn't say that your answer is any more helpful.

Comment: The OP knows how to define single-parameter functions such as `(define (f x) x)`. He specifically said he was "puzzled here mostly on the multiple parameters," and your original answer was essentially "why would you ever want to write a multiple-parameter function?" Even your edited response ignores the OP's main concern and shows a single-parameter function.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million: fair enough. Thanks for retracting the negative points. I had good intentions.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million: thanks for reminding me to put this in tail call form. I had forgotten my original intention to do that.

Answer (score -1):

```
(define (takes-three-args a b c)
   (takes-three-args (* 2 c) (+ 1 b) (/ 1 a))) ;; Loops Forever and consumes
                                               ;; an ever-increasing amount of memory.
```

Comment: This seems like a poor choice of algorithm to answer the question, especially considering your response to the other answer.

Comment: What algorithm? The OP wanted to know how to define a more-than-one-arg function and how to do recursion, and I defined a more-than-one-arg recursive function, while the guy writing the other answer basically said "why would you ever want to write a multiple-parameter function?" (Although he's since edited his answer to show some code, using a function that only accepts one argument, explicitly ignoring that the OP said he was particularly confused about multi-parameter functions, and it isn't even tail recusrive.)